# understanding decorators in python

Tags: python

I am having an object I cant touch, but would like to log the method calls. I don't really understand decorators, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do something like this

```
import pprint

 class myTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def test(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():            
            setattr(self, k, v)   

def wrap(o, method, **kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print '%s set to %s' %(k, v)
        getattr(o, method)(**kwargs)


o = myTest()
d = {'b':2,'c': 3}

wrap(o, 'test', **d)
pprint.pprint(vars(o))
```

such that I can decorate a regular method call and do it somehow like this:

```
@mydecorator
o.test(**d)
```

and would get a similar result. Then I would not have to replace all the method calls in the script

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a chain of function decorators in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

Comment: You need to apply decorator at function definition, not at function call. Try to read [this article](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/)

Answer (score 1):

The question mentioned in the comments has some excellent explainations of decorators, so you should read that first - [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

As to your specific question. As you can't touch the `myTest` object definition, you can just change it's methods at runtime! You can do this just to your instance:

```
import pprint

class myTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def test(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():            
            setattr(self, k, v)   

def log_calls(fn):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print '%s called with args %s and kwargs %s' % (repr(fn), repr(args), repr(kwargs))
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

o = myTest()
o.test = log_calls(o.test) # equivalent to applying the decorator at method
                           # definition, but only applies to this instance of myTest

d = {'b':2, 'c':3}
o.test(**d)
pprint.pprint(vars(o))
```

Outputs:

```
<bound method myTest.test of <__main__.myTest object at 0x0000000002EE07F0>> called with args () and kwargs {'c': 3, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'test': <function wrapped at 0x0000000002EDDEB8>}
```

Or modify the class itself:

```
myTest.test = log_calls(myTest.test)
o = myTest()

d = {'b':2, 'c':3}
o.test(**d)
pprint.pprint(vars(o))
```

This is called monkey patching - you can find some more info here [What is a monkey patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patch)